# How to tell (webpack) bundler to transform dependent project's tsconfig path

Tags: typescript, webpack, bundler, monorepo

Suppose there is a monorepo workspace. The monorepo has an app sub-workspace(`/workspace/app`) and a component sub-workspace(`/workspace/component`). In order to develop app and component library with hot module reload enabled, in app sub-workspace's tsconfig, we may use the paths configuration:

```json
{ // /workspace/app/tsconfig.json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@lib/component": ["../component"]
    }
  }
}
```

Now in component sub-workspace's tsconfig, there may be other paths:

```json
{ // /workspace/component/tsconfig.json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Either `/workspace/component/tsconfig.json` is ignored by webpack or the path `@/*` is not correctly handled by webpack, the result is codes in `/workspace/component/src` that imports from `@/xxx` is not correctly understood, so the app cannot compile.

When each sub-workspace is transpiled to js independently, I know ts-patch with typescript-transform-paths plugin is able to transform the `@/xxx` import path to the correct relative path with respect to the sub-workspace's root.

Now when directly using webpack to handle all of those sub-workspaces, what is the correct configuration to make them transformed?

Reference/Example with next.js/webpack: https://github.com/belgattitude/nextjs-monorepo-example/discussions/4555

Comment: Specifically, I just learned resolve.alias configuration. However, what if multiple component libraries all have the same `@/*` alias? Is it possible to provide a resolution function (that I can get the file calling `import`) or distinguish different sub-workspaces who have the same path alias?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a webpack plugin similar to https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin/blob/master/src/plugin.ts

It intercepts webpack's resolver (it internally uses `enhanced-resolve`), if the root path is another sub-workspace, it will search for the tsconfig file, then resolve the path.

To enable:

```js
// next.config.mjs
import { MonorepoResolvePlugin } from './monorepo-resolve-plugin.mjs';
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    
    // ...other codes

    config.resolve = {
      ...config.resolve,
      plugins: [
        ...config.resolve.plugins,
        new MonorepoResolvePlugin({
          appRoot: process.cwd(),
          workspaceParents: [
            '../../apps',
            '/workspaces/nextjs-monorepo-example/packages/',
          ],
        }),
      ],
    };
  }
};
```

```js
// monorepo-resolve-plugin.mjs

import path from 'path';
import createInnerContext from 'enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerContext.js';
import getInnerRequest from 'enhanced-resolve/lib/getInnerRequest.js';
import * as tsconfigPaths from 'tsconfig-paths';

function subdirOf(parent, dir) {
  const relative = path.relative(parent, dir);
  return !relative.startsWith('..') && !path.isAbsolute(relative) && relative;
}

export class MonorepoResolvePlugin {
  constructor({ appRoot, workspaceParents = [] }) {
    this.appRoot = appRoot;
    this.workspaceParents = workspaceParents;
    this.cache = {};
  }

  apply(resolver) {
    const target = resolver.ensureHook('internal-resolve');
    const readJson = createReadJsonAsync(resolver.fileSystem);
    const fileExist = createFileExistAsync(resolver.fileSystem);

    resolver
      .getHook('raw-resolve')
      .tapAsync(
        'MonorepoResolvePlugin',
        (request, resolveContext, callback) => {
          const innerRequest = getInnerRequest(resolver, request);

          if (
            !innerRequest ||
            request?.request?.startsWith('.') ||
            request?.request?.startsWith('..')
          ) {
            return callback();
          }

          // current appRoot's alias is handled by webpack
          if (subdirOf(this.appRoot, request.path) !== false) {
            return callback();
          }

          let cacheEntry = undefined;

          for (const [parent, entry] of Object.entries(this.cache)) {
            if (subdirOf(parent, request.path) !== false) {
              cacheEntry = entry;
              break;
            }
          }

          if (cacheEntry === undefined) {
            findTsConfig: for (const workspaceParent of this.workspaceParents) {
              const subdir = subdirOf(workspaceParent, request.path);
              if (!subdir) {
                continue;
              }

              const subdirParts = subdir.split('/');
              subdirParts.unshift('');
              let maybeWorkspaceRoot = workspaceParent;
              while (subdirParts.length) {
                maybeWorkspaceRoot = path.join(
                  maybeWorkspaceRoot,
                  subdirParts.shift()
                );
                const loadResult = tsconfigPaths.loadConfig(maybeWorkspaceRoot);
                if (loadResult.resultType === 'success') {
                  cacheEntry = {
                    absoluteBaseUrl: loadResult.absoluteBaseUrl,
                    matchPath: tsconfigPaths.createMatchPathAsync(
                      loadResult.absoluteBaseUrl,
                      loadResult.paths
                    ),
                  };
                  this.cache[maybeWorkspaceRoot] = cacheEntry;
                  break findTsConfig;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          if (cacheEntry === undefined) {
            return callback();
          }

          const { absoluteBaseUrl, matchPath } = cacheEntry;

          // reference: https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin/blob/master/src/plugin.ts
          matchPath(
            innerRequest,
            readJson,
            fileExist,
            ['.ts', '.tsx'],
            (err, foundMatch) => {
              if (err) {
                return callback(err);
              }

              if (!foundMatch) {
                return callback();
              }

              const newRequest = {
                ...request,
                request: foundMatch,
                path: absoluteBaseUrl,
              };

              return resolver.doResolve(
                target,
                newRequest,
                `Resolved request '${innerRequest}' to '${foundMatch}' using tsconfig.json paths mapping`,
                createInnerContext({ resolveContext }),
                (err2, result2) => {
                  // Pattern taken from:
                  // https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/blob/42ff594140582c3f8f86811f95dea7bf6774a1c8/lib/AliasPlugin.js#L44
                  if (err2) {
                    return callback(err2);
                  }

                  // Don't allow other aliasing or raw request
                  if (result2 === undefined) {
                    return callback(undefined, undefined);
                  }

                  callback(undefined, result2);
                }
              );
            }
          );
        }
      );
  }
}

function createReadJsonAsync(fileSystem) {
  return (path2, callback2) => {
    fileSystem.readJson(path2, (err, json) => {
      // If error assume file does not exist
      if (err || !json) {
        callback2();
        return;
      }
      callback2(undefined, json);
    });
  };
}

function createFileExistAsync(fileSystem) {
  return (path2, callback2) => {
    fileSystem.stat(path2, (err, stats) => {
      // If error assume file does not exist
      if (err) {
        callback2(undefined, false);
        return;
      }
      callback2(undefined, stats ? stats.isFile() : false);
    });
  };
}
```